# Range of x such that all probabilities are being satisfied

Tags: probability

If $A, B, C$ are mutually exclusive events such that $P(A)=\frac{3 x+1}{3}$, $P(B)=\frac{1-x}{4}$ and $P(C)=\frac{1-2 x}{2}$. Then the set of possible values of $x$ are

> What i considered was as all are mutually exclusive so we have $P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B)$ , similairly others (2 more) and also $P(A\cup B \cup C) = P(A)+ P(B) + P(C) $ , so finding the range of x means we need all the above probabilitites to lie between 0 and 1 , but is it necessary to solve all 7 inequalities to get the range of x possible ? Or it can be done shorter ?

Comment: Basically you have 14 inequalities due the two bounds 0 and 1. I would regard all these cases.

Comment: Okay so its necessary we evaluate all right @callculus42 and take intersection?

Comment: Like here : https://tardigrade.in/question/events-a-b-c-are-mutually-exclusive-events-such-that-p-a-3x-nixqzczd they just solve 8 of them , its not correct right ?

Comment: I don't know if it is right in general or maybe it is right in this case only. Have you solved the other 6 cases?

Comment: I checked and got that it matches sith the given answer. I think its because the other 6 gives the common range to be more or equal to  what its given by the other 8 , so its just true in this case only ? Am i right ? @callculus42

Comment: OK. But I cannot say either if it is true in general.

Comment: Hnm sure me too think that